# Restore the mySQL database from files - Windows server

Tags: mysql, wordpress, windows-server-2012

I have tried everything I can find now for over 3 days straight to recover a mySQL database on Windows.

**What happened?**

I have a Windows Server 2012 that crashed which had WordPress on it and the  MySQL 5.1 database for WordPress with no backups.  Is there no way to recover from this with a database backup even if you have all the files?

**What I have tried!**

**Attempt 1 recovery (try to add the database from the crashed server to the current mySQL instance):**

1. I reinstalled a new MySQL 5.1 on to the new Windows Server 2012
   system and I moved just the /data/wordpress953 folder over
   “completely” from the crashed system (which was working fine) into
   the /data folder of the new MySQL install.
2. I start up MySQL and login just fine.  I see my database.  I see all the tables.  However, if I go to a table to view it and I get the following error.

### 1146 = Table ‘Wordpress953.wp_commentmeta’ doesn’t exist

**Attempt 2 recovery (try to completely replace the current mySQL instance files from the crashed server on top and overwrite the new instance):**

1. I completely move over the /data folder from the old server replacing it on the new server
2. I completely move over the /program files/mysql folder over from the old server onto the new server
3. I completely move over the /program files (x86)/mysql folder over from the old server
4. I startup mysql and go to phpmyadmin and get the following error when I try and login:

### 1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

I figure I just need to fix the root password so I attempt to change the root password using this process https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dyc5b3yT2tI but it fails to even start mySQL to change the password.

**Please help with an answer of something I haven't tried....**

Answer (score 0):

**Ok, I got it!!**

### The procedure is.

1. Install vanilla mySQL on new server (I had already done that)
2. Stop mySQL service
3. Move ONLY the C:\Program Data\data\wordpress953 (the innodb database you want to restore) folder over “intact” “as is”.
4. And, move ONLY the ibdata1 file and ib_logfiles off of the original C:\Program Data\data\ *root* to the new mySQL server. Leave the C:\Program Data\data\mysql folder “as is” from the vanilla install
5. Re-Start mySQL service

It was a bit of a puzzle because it was basically an “incarnation” of what I was doing but you have to **only** change/do certain things. The C:\Program Data\data\ibdata1 file down one level in the root went with the C:\Program Data\wordpress953 folder but apparently not with \mysql.